# Python3 Replace module call with variable

Tags: python, mongodb, collections, pymongo

I am writing a script to query a mongoDB collection using pymongo.

My database has three collections and I am asking the user to pick a collection and then want to return all confirmed guests from that collection.

Currently, I have:

```
collectiontosearch = input("What event would you like to display? : ")
collection = db.collectiontosearch
print(collection)

for people in collection.find({"Confirmed": "Yes"}):
            pprint.pprint(people)
```

But instead of searching on the assigned value of 'collectiontosearch', it is searching on the plain text 'collectiontosearch' which obviously is not a collection in my database.  Any idea how I can get pymongo to take my variable value here instead of the strict text of my variable name?  I realize this is probably pretty basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Collection is accessible on `MongoClient` instance by indexing or by `get_database` instance method.

Use:

```
collectiontosearch = input("What event would you like to display? : ")
collection = db[collectiontosearch]
...
```

Or:

```
collection = db.get_database(collectiontosearch)
```